# Python __call__() is this an implicit classmethod?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass, class-method

I want to implement a singleton pattern in python, and I liked the pattern described in the http://www.python-course.eu/python3_metaclasses.php.

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class SingletonClass(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass
class RegularClass():
    pass
x = SingletonClass()
y = SingletonClass()
print(x == y)
x = RegularClass()
y = RegularClass()
print(x == y)
```

And the code works perfect. But, the `__call__()` does not have the `self`, and it also does not have `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` declaration.

But, in the Python data model https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__ the `__call__()` method has a self in the arguments.

The code does not work if I pass `self`, or declare as `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`.

Can someone please explain the logic of the syntax behind the `__call__()` method.

Comment: *The code does not work if I pass self*: how did you 'pass self' here? If you *renamed* `cls` to `self` (everywhere in the function, not just the parameter), the code would continue to work. Hell, rename it to `gabbledygook` and it'll work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Naming the first argument of a method `cls` or `self` are *just a convention*. The `__call__` method *does* have a self argument, only it is *named* `cls` here. That's because for a metaclass, the method is bound to a class object, and the name reflects this.

The same convention is applied to `@classmethod` methods; the first argument is a class, always, due to the nature of how a `classmethod` object is bound, so it makes sense to name that first argument `cls`.

But you are free to name that first argument anything else. It is not the name that makes a classmethod or a regular method or a method on a metatype work. All that using `self` or `cls` does is *document what type of object this is*, making it easier for other developers to mentally track what is going on.

So no, this is not an implicit class method. That first argument is not bound to the `Singleton` metaclass object, it is bound to the class that was called. That makes sense, because that class object is an instance of the `Singleton` metatype.

If you want to dive into how *binding* works (the process that causes that first argument to be passed in, whatever the name), you can read up on the [*Descriptor HOWTO*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). TLDR: functions, `property`, `classmethod` and `staticmethod` objects are all *descriptors*, and whenever you access them as an attribute on a supporting object such as an instance or a class, they are bound, often causing a *different* object to be returned as a result, which when called passes in the bound object to the actual function.

Answer (score 0):

Martin's answer says it all. I am adding this so maybe a different wording can throw in more light for different people:

## Python **call**() is this an implicit classmethod?

No. But all "metaclass" methods are implicit "class methods" for the classes that use that metaclass.

That is implicit when we take in account the fact that classes are simply instances of the metaclass. From the language point of view, a class behave almost exactly like any other instance - and any interactions with a class that would trigger dunder (`__magic__`) methods in an object - like using the "+, -, *, /" operators, or index retrieval with `[ ]`, or calling them with `(  )` trigger the corresponding methods on its class. That is ordinarily `type`.

And, as put in the other answer, Python does not care what name you ut on the first argument of a method. For metaclasses it makes sense to use  `cls` there, since the "instances" the methods are dealing with are metaclasses.  As it makes sense that the first argument to a metaclass' `__new__` method be named `metacls` (like in the example bellow). Because the new "cls" is the object we get after calling `type.__new__` - the only call possible in pure Python that will actually create a class object.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace):
         ...
         cls = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)
         ...
         return cls
```

(Now, still on the topic of the question: `__new__` **is** a special case
of an implicit static method (even for ordinary classes that are not intended to be metaclasses) - to which Python specially add the first argument, using a different mechanism than what is done to regular `classmethod`s. Thats is why the `super().__new__` call above needs to include the metacls as the first parameter)